# Burninate and blacklist request: [career-*] [job-*] [resume]

Tags: discussion, tags, career

This is not a duplicate of this: [Usefulness of [career-development] and [career-transition] tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/usefulness-of-career-development-and-career-transition-tags) ... it's time for them to be blacklisted. The narrowness of scope of what actually would be on topic here is so narrow that it's pretty much invisible. **All it does is invite off topic posts.**

We absolutely can and should keep the tag around for historically significant posts. According to Meta, we can do this. But it should be blacklisted for all future posts. See [Mark a tag as a historical significance only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252898/mark-a-tag-as-a-historical-significance-only)

This has come up many times before, for example:

- [Offering Solutions to the Career and Jobs Tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/offering-solutions-to-the-career-and-jobs-tags) (2011) (Note: this question didn't suggest blacklisting because blacklisting didn't exist when it was discussed)
- [Blacklist [career]](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3279/blacklist-career) (2012)
- [Posse request: jobs/career/etc. tag cleanup](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/posse-request-jobs-career-etc-tag-cleanup) (2013)
- [Career-Transition Tag inappropriate?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/career-transition-tag-inappropriate) (Early 2014)
- [There seems to be some contradictory guidance with respect to asking career development questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/there-seems-to-be-some-contradictory-guidance-with-respect-to-asking-career-deve) (Early 2014)
- [Improve question quality by informing askers of expectations in some career related tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/improve-question-quality-by-informing-askers-of-expectations-in-some-career-rela) (Late 2014)

For crying out loud, this is the [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) tag wiki:

> Do not use this tag. Click "info" for better alternatives.

This is the [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) tag wiki:

> Career advice is off-topic per Help Center. 99% of questions with this tag are off-topic and will be closed. Study other questions under this tag closely that aren't closed before asking your question, if you want any chance of it not being closed. Closed questions add up to a possible question-ban

Bottom line... there is an awful lot of bad here, and very, very little good. It's nigh impossible to write an on-topic question with these tags. A lot of those are out of date because **The Workplace had not even graduated until February 2014**. Some relevant comments (emphasis mine):

- [Rachel](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1130/rachel) [Jan 6 '13 at 18:30](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/usefulness-of-career-development-and-career-transition-tags#comment13618_5427) (this is the best that can be managed by someone that *likes* the tag):

> I think [career-development] does serve a purpose, and it's one of my favorite tags to browse on the site. Career advice isn't the same as career development. We can't advise someone on what career path they should take, but we can answer some questions about career development for software developers. I'm not sure about [career-transition] though... **I can't think of any cases where it could be on-topic here.**

- [@Yannis Rizos♦︎](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis-rizos) [Jan 19 '13 at 22:19](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/usefulness-of-career-development-and-career-transition-tags#comment13769_5446)

> This is all good, but irrelevant if the tags aren't used as they are supposed to be used. If a lot of people use [career-development] to ask career advice questions, then the **tag is problematic and should probably go away.** The two topics are distinct, but their differences are subtle, and become even more subtle if we consider non native English speakers.

---

### It's time for them to go.

Comment: related: [Mark a tag as a historical significance only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252898/mark-a-tag-as-a-historical-significance-only#comment825864_252898): "...we've done this exact thing with the [code-golf tag over on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759)"

Comment: [tag:resume] tag is probably worth taking care of too; it was included in that "late 2014" [tag tip request](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6983/31260). Another slippery tag seems to be [tag:portfolio]

Comment: I am doing my part, using my close votes as fast as I get them.

Comment: [Burnination](http://www.homestarrunner.com/disk4of12.html) continues.

Comment: 10K users and moderators are additionally welcome to [visit tools page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days) to check delete- and undelete-worthy questions in cleaned up tags

Comment: see also: [Structured Tag Cleanup Initiative Phase II Planning](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7287/31260)